# Google data studio api cannot add scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, looker-studio

I am trying to build a system where I can programmatically give view access to specific emails to my google data studio reports.

I am following the Data studio API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api). I have enabled google data studio API. But when I try to manually add scope in the second step it shows an error **The following scope(s) were not added because they are invalid. Please update or remove these scopes**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. This is a recent bug. The Data Studio team is looking into it. I'll update this post once this is fixed.

Comment: Okay thank you.. please let me know when it is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be tracked through Issue Tracker [Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187908884) and also you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring  this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue)